# Php and Java Sha1 methods gives different results

Tags: java, php, unicode, utf-8, decode

I am trying to convert a php code to java code but at sha1 , i am getting different strings from php and java.For example,I wrote a code for php;

```
$password = 'pass123';
$hassedPasswordInDB = 'e1NTSEF9ZWxtNWlJcjJOVkVaenphZjA5dnlnUWFYdVlHaEU3dzQ=';
$sPasswordHash = base64_decode(substr(base64_decode($hassedPasswordInDB), 6));
$sSecretSalt = substr($sPasswordHash, 20); // $sSecretSalt is ��8 here
$sPasswordHash = substr($sPasswordHash, 0, 20);
$hashedPassword = sha1($password.$sSecretSalt); // $hashedPassword is 7a59b9888af6355119cf369fd3dbf2810697b981
```

And I wrote code for java too ;

```
    String password = "pass123";
    String hassedPasswordInDB = "e1NTSEF9ZWxtNWlJcjJOVkVaenphZjA5dnlnUWFYdVlHaEU3dzQ=";
    String subFirstDecode = new String(Base64Coder.decode(hassedPasswordInDB)).substring(6);
    String sPasswordHash = new String(Base64Coder.decode(subFirstDecode));
    String secretSalt = sPasswordHash.substring(19); // secretSalt is ��8
    sPasswordHash = sPasswordHash.substring(0, 19);
    String hashedPassword = sha1(password + secretSalt); //hashedPassword is b15fe1e7e0abce8284d3695af6c57d7540387ae4
```

And Java sha1 method ;

```
private static String sha1(String input) {
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        digest.update(input.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++)
            hexString.append(String.format("%02X", 0xFF & messageDigest[i]));
        return hexString.toString().toLowerCase();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

As a result ,when i tried with Utf-8 string like "abcabc" it works but same codes with complicated inputs ,which is like "��8", gives two different outputs.

```
Java : b15fe1e7e0abce8284d3695af6c57d7540387ae4,
PHP  : 7a59b9888af6355119cf369fd3dbf2810697b98
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: I don't know Java enough to help but I would break this down further. You can start at either end but, for instance, ignore everything except SHA-1 and work on that. Use a complex string such as `A♠` to make sure you don't have encoding problems. Get a working example of a SHA-1 of that string that works in both PHP and Java. Once you know that works, take a step back and work on your string/encoding things. For the Java code, always create a variable that is a single step (function) and compare the results with the PHP version, and repeat function-by-function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your Java code: while in PHP a string is just a sequence of **bytes** (cf. [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details)), in Java it is a sequence of **characters**. Characters in Java are UTF-16 code points.

All transformations between `byte[]` and `String` use an encoding, so you should avoid such transformations if you can and specify the encoding when you do (use the [`String(byte[], Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D,java.nio.charset.Charset)) constructor or equivalent). Otherwise you'll end up using your system's default encoding (probably UTF-8 in your case).

What happens in your case is:

- the `sPasswordHash` string has length 23, while the original byte array had 24 bytes: there are a lot of encoding errors, so many sequences of bytes are replaced by the [replacement character `�`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)),
- to compensate you call `sPassword.substring(19)` (should be 20), which excludes the first 19 characters. You end up with a slightly different salt.

You should rather work on `byte` arrays: it is less comfortable, but safer.

```java
      String password = "pass123";
      String hashedPasswordInDB = "e1NTSEF9ZWxtNWlJcjJOVkVaenphZjA5dnlnUWFYdVlHaEU3dzQ=";
      // This should be ASCII
      final String firstDecode = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(hashedPasswordInDB), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
      final byte[] hashAndSalt = Base64.getDecoder().decode(firstDecode.substring("{SSHA}".length()));
      final byte[] passwordHash = Arrays.copyOf(hashAndSalt, 20);
      final byte[] salt = Arrays.copyOfRange(hashAndSalt, 20, hashAndSalt.length);
      final byte[] passwordBytes = password.getBytes();
      final byte[] passwordAndSalt = Arrays.copyOf(passwordBytes, passwordBytes.length + salt.length);
      System.arraycopy(salt, 0, passwordAndSalt, passwordBytes.length, salt.length);
      System.out.println(sha1(passwordAndSalt));
```

(I slightly modified the `sha1` method to accept a byte array instead of `String`)

Remark: Since Java 8 there is a base 64 encoder/decoder in the JRE (cf. [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html)).

Comment: It works.That was a perfect solution.Thanks a lot.